# Zend Framework 2: Session SaveHandler - save IP Address

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-session

I am using a custom Session\SaveHandler with the following DbTableGatewayOptions:

```
        $gwOpts = new DbTableGatewayOptions();
        $gwOpts->setDataColumn('data');
        $gwOpts->setIdColumn('id');
        $gwOpts->setLifetimeColumn('lifetime');
        $gwOpts->setModifiedColumn('modified');
        $gwOpts->setNameColumn('name');

        $saveHandler = new DbTableGateway($this->tblGW, $gwOpts);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager();
        if ($this->sessionConfig) {
            $sessionConfig = new \Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig();
            $sessionConfig->setOptions($this->sessionConfig);
            $sessionManager->setConfig($sessionConfig);
        }
        $sessionManager->setSaveHandler($saveHandler);
        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
        $sessionManager->start();
```

What's the best way to add 2 additional fields for `user_agent` and `client_ip`? Is that even possible?

Comment: Hi Alex, 
Did you get this worked, add user_agent and ip ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add ip as session variable using for example `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`